# Foreign Key Not Populating with Primary Key Values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have searched for an answer but am not finding it. I have 2 tables. Both have an auto-generated PK. The PK from table 2 is an FK in table 1. Since they are both auto-generated I assumed the FK in table 1 would populate with the value that is auto-generated from table 2 but it is not working. The FK in table 1 ends up null. Here is my SQL code for creating table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_tbl (
EmployeeID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
LastName varchar(20) not null,
FirstName varchar(20) not null,
Age varchar(3) not null,
JobID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES JobTitle_tbl(JobID),
)
```

and here is table 2:

```
create table JobTitle_tbl(
JobID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
EEO1Classification varchar(50) not null,
Exempt_nonexempt_status varchar(20) not null,
)
```

I also have some insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO Employee_tbl
    (LastName, FirstName, Age)
Values
    ('Smith', 'John', '50'),
    ...
```

and:

```
INSERT into JobTitle_tbl (EEO1Classification, Job_title, )
VALUES ('Office/Clerical', 'Accounting Clerk', ),
```

Why is the FK value showing null when I query table 1?

Comment: Can you please reduce the verbiage in your question? Also a FK is not auto generated. you will have to explicitly insert it in the child table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign keys will not auto-populate, as it doesn't know what foreign key to use.  You need to either insert the rows into the JobTitle_tbl table, then select the IDs back out (or use @@identity if using sql server)

```
select id from JobTitle_tbl where Job_title = ''
```

Another option would be to update your insert statements to include the primary key, although you'll have to allow identity inserts first.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT JobTitle_tbl ON
into the JobTitle_tbl (id, title) values (1, 'Manager')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT JobTitle_tbl OFF
```

In either case, you'll need to then update your first insert statements with the ID that you have.

```
insert into Employee_tbl (LastName, FirstName, JobID) values ('Smith', 'John', 1)
```

Comment: so am i understanding this right? there is no way to have the fk auto populate?

Comment: @JohnStewart: no, the FK can **never** automatically be filled - how would that row "know" what parent row it belongs to!?!?? That's something that **you** as the programmer know - it's up to you to fill the proper value into the FK to establish the link to the parent row.

Comment: @Shawn: I would recommend to use [SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Good point Marc_s.  I don't usually use either, but wanted to provide the option for John.