# Added a FK to my customer table from Bill table, can not add data to fk column

Tags: sql, oracle10g, foreign-keys

[Foreign Key Not Populating with Primary Key Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046879/foreign-key-not-populating-with-primary-key-values)

I did a lot of searching on the site, but I am relatively new to writing code for a database. I read a few threads like the one listed above, but I was unable to utilize the information within to solve my problem. I have two tables, customer and billing. The customer table is below:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;

CUST_ID                   NAME            BILL_NUM
-------------------- ------------------- ----------
432                  MICHAEL MAYS  
433                  VILMA PACULAN    
434                  RUBY PUKE   
435                  ROWENA JOHNSON    
436                  MAGIC JOHNSON    
437                  DARTH VADER    
438                  OBI WAN   
439                  YODA    
440                  STEWIE GRIFFIN
441                  EVIL MONKEY    
442                  HARRY POTTER
```

Bill table:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM BILL
  2  ;

  BILL_NUM      TOTAL
---------- ----------
      1000        5.5
      1001        7.4
      1002       12.5
      1003      14.56
      1004      25.36
      1005      66.66
      1006      99.97
      1007      56.67
      1008       5.23
      1009      87.25
      1010      36.17
```

As you can see in the customer table the FK Bill_Num is null. I need to know how to insert the data into the column, to match the PK data? I am using oracle 10g SQLPlus. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are the tables `Customer` and `Bill` linked?? How do you know **which** bills belong to Customer No. 442 - Harry Potter ??

Comment: Is this not the wrong way around?  CUST_ID should be in the BILL table, not BILL_NUM in CUSTOMER.  Normally a bill belongs to a single customer and a customer can have many bills.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can. As you haven't linked them previously you'll have to do it manually...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your current data set up, there is no common column (implicit or explicit) that would link these two tables. As a result, it is impossible to automatically link the tables.

You either need a transaction table in the form:
CUST_ID | Bill_NUM (many to many)

Or as Graeme stated put the CUST_ID on the Bill table as right now your many-to-one relationship will be the opposite of what would be expected.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization - A good place to start on normalizing a database