# Foreign key showing null value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to show the foreign key value that is extracted from another table. 
The codes that i've used:

Code for first table:

```
CREATE TABLE trip (
    tripID  INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    startTime   TIME,
    endTime     TIME,
    tripDate    DATE,
    price       VARCHAR(5),
    databaseID  INT(10),
    FOREIGN KEY (databaseID)
       REFERENCES databasestorage(databaseID)
);
```

code for second table:

```
CREATE TABLE databasestorage (
    databaseID  INT(10) PRIMARY KEY,                    
    location        VARCHAR(40)
);
```

After inserting the values into both tables, in the `trip` table, `databaseID` still shows as `null` while all other columns are correct. How do i make it such that `databaseID` in my `trip` table shows the value of `databaseID` from the `databasestorage` table?

Comment: @JaydipJ I inserted into `databasestorage` table first and `trip` table second

Comment: Add insert script as well

Comment: `INSERT INTO databasestorage(databaseID, location)
 VALUES('1021', 'Caulfield')`  for the first table,   

`INSERT INTO trip(tripID, startTime, endTime, tripDate, price)
 VALUES('101', '20:20:00', '20:40:00', '2016-10-22', '$5.25')` for the second

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key Not Populating with Primary Key Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046879/foreign-key-not-populating-with-primary-key-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass primary key of `databasestorage` table while inserting data into `trip` table right?

```
INSERT INTO databasestorage(databaseID, location) VALUES('1021', 'Caulfield')
```

For trip table you need to explicit pass the value for `databaseID` column in trip table, **foreign key will not automatically inserted**

```
                                                        ---------v
INSERT INTO trip(tripID, startTime, endTime, tripDate, price,databaseID)
VALUES('101', '20:20:00', '20:40:00', '2016-10-22', '$5.25','1021')
                                                         -----^
```

Comment: You are right, it doesn't show as `null` anymore, do we have to always manually update the foreign key ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

Add `auto_increment` to table definition:

For first:

```
CREATE TABLE databasestorage (
    databaseID  INT(10) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    location        VARCHAR(40)
);
```

For second:

```
CREATE TABLE trip (
    tripID  INT(10) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    startTime   TIME,
    endTime     TIME,
    tripDate    DATE,
    price       VARCHAR(5),
    databaseID  INT(10),
    FOREIGN KEY (databaseID)
        REFERENCES databasestorage(databaseID)
);
```

**ADDITION** *(Insert query)*

```
INSERT INTO trip(tripID, startTime, endTime, tripDate, price) VALUES('101', '20:20:00', '20:40:00', '2016-10-22', '$5.25');
```

In this query no need to pass value for `tripID` it's an `auto_increment` field I think you are passing `databaseID` value to `tripID`. So the value you are getting after insert for `databasestorage.databaseID` should be passed in `trip.databaseID`

So final query would be:

```
INSERT INTO trip(startTime, endTime, tripDate, price, databaseID) VALUES('20:20:00', '20:40:00', '2016-10-22', '$5.25', 101);
```

And as the `trip.databaseID` is `INT` field no need to add quotes(`''`);

Comment: i tried to run first code but it returns error code: 1005, Can't create table 's345.trip' (errno:150)

Comment: @DarioOngsono change the order of table creation; first primary key field table then table using primary key as foreign key;

Comment: i just tried it, it worked in terms of table creation but after i input into `databasestorage` table first and `trip` table second, it still shows as `null` unfortunately.

Comment: @DarioOngsono Can you please share insert code for `trip` table?

Comment: `
INSERT INTO trip(tripID, startTime, endTime, tripDate, price)
 VALUES('101', '20:20:00', '20:40:00', '2016-10-22', '$5.25')`

Comment: @DarioOngsono check the addition;

Comment: Unfortunately, your final query did not work. It returned, `Error Code : 1452
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`s344`.`trip`, CONSTRAINT `trip_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`databaseID`) REFERENCES `databasestorage` (`databaseID`))`

Comment: @DarioOngsono This is because the record doesn't exist in `databasestorage` you are passing in `trip` right or not?

Comment: We use foreign key only for this check if there is a parent we can add a child to it;

Comment: I have always prioritized my actions on `databasestorage` table first, i'm sure the record exist in it. as JayDipJ mentioned above, i have no manually input `databaseID` by myself in `trip` table.

Comment: @DarioOngsono Then there must be a record in `databasestorage` table with that value and if you want to manually input this value then why you are using foreign key? First you need to create record in `databasestorage` then get the last `insertId` and then pass that id to `trip.databaseID` or maybe any other key you have with some other inserts in `databasestorage`;