# SQL foreign key returns NULL

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I am quite new in SQL and would like to ask for assistance as I am struggling with a foreign key issue. I've been searching and googling for couple of days with no result.

My problem is that I am creating 2 tables where one is with primary key and second one with primary key and foreign key. You can see below the example code:

```
CREATE TABLE CarList
(
    C_Id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Car_Model nvarchar(255),
)
```

Than I am inserting data into this table like below:

```
INSERT INTO CarList (Car_Model)
VALUES ('AUDI'), ('BMW'), ('PORSCHE')
```

Than I am creating the second table with foreign key as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE Series
(
    S_Id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Car_Series nvarchar(255),
    Car_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CarList(C_Id)
)
```

And as final step I am inserting the data for the second table:

```
INSERT INTO Series(Car_Series)
VALUES ('911c'), ('330d'), ('80TDI')
```

Here my problem actually comes. Once I set all and call the table with the foreign key the column which should have the foreign key value is shown as `NULL`. I've done the relationship between the both tables in the SQL Server Management Studio but the result is still the same.

Then I am trying to map both tables with joins and still the same. All what I've read on the internet is basically not saying how the value should be appearing in the foreign key column or at least I am not getting the point. I want the first table car models to be corresponding to the second table calling them by ID. So if I want to call ID 1 from the first table which is AUDI to get on the second table the ID of the series 80TDI.

Can you please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key Not Populating with Primary Key Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046879/foreign-key-not-populating-with-primary-key-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert a value for the foreign key when populating the *Series* table, for example:

```
INSERT INTO Series(Car_Series)
VALUES
('911c', 3),
('330d', 2),
('80TDI', 1)
```

As far as I can see (I'm not big on cars!) your foreign key points to a table that denotes the *manufacturer* of the car (eg Audi, BMW). When you're adding the data into *Series* Sql Server doesn't know the manufacturer (it knows less about cars than me!), so you have to tell it.

The foreign key constraint just means that Sql wouldn't, say key you add a Golf as follows:

```
 INSERT INTO Series(Car_Series)
VALUES
('Golf', 4)
```

unless you'd already set up Volkswagen with a key of 4 in your `*CarList*` table.

Incidentally, you can set the foreign key column to not allow nulls - this is good practice if you want to ensure that all its entries reference the parent table.

Comment: Thank you Mark! Now is quite clear. The only thing which comes in my mind is - what if I have really huge amount of data to insert into the second table? Wouldn't adding the corresponding number take too much time? Is there maybe an automated option for this or I have to go with this approach?

Comment: No it shouldn't increase the overhead noticably as long as its it's in the same insert statement. Also the volume of data is low as it's just an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
you need to insert data in  foreign key when populating the Series table

  CREATE TABLE CarList
(
C_Id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Car_Model nvarchar(255),
)

INSERT INTO CarList (Car_Model)
VALUES
('AUDI'),
('BMW'),
('PORSCHE')

CREATE TABLE Series
(
S_Id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Car_Series nvarchar(255),
Car_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CarList(C_Id)
)

INSERT INTO Series(Car_Series,Car_Id)
VALUES
('911c', 3),
('330d', 2),
('80TDI', 1)

select * from CarList a join Series b on a.C_Id=b.Car_Id
where C_Id=1
```

output

```
C_Id    Car_Model   S_Id    Car_Series  Car_Id
1         AUDI       3       80TDI        1
```

Comment: Thank you Chanukya!