# Foreign Key appearing as NULL in table. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I am having trouble properly inserting a foreign key into a table. I have created a couple of tables using this format:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Example
(
    ExampleID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Example VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    Example VARCHAR(6) NULL,
    Example VARCHAR(MAX),
    Example VARCHAR(MAX),
    ExampleFK INT, 
    Example VARCHAR(MAX),
    etc.
)
```

And have inserted values to this table following this format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Example

INSERT INTO tbl_Example (Example, Example, Example, Example, etc.)
VALUES ('data', 'data', 'data', 'data', etc.)
```

And at the end of my code have placed this in order to add a foreign key to my original table:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Example 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (ExampleFK) REFERENCES tbl_Example1 (Example1ID)
```

For some reason after executed the foreign key column is filled completely with NULL. I have tried adjusting the placement of my foreign key column and have used varying forms of syntax in order to create the foreign key and correct the issue but nothing has worked. The key and connection appear to have been made, it is just not appearing properly in my table for some reason.

Edit: The values should not be NULL. `Example1ID` has no NULL values.

Comment: Hint: `ExampleFK INT NOT NULL,`

Comment: Foreign key columns can be null. That's perfectly normal.

Comment: @TheImpaler Unless he want it not nullable and forgot to use `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Foreign keys and column nullability are two different things.

Comment: `ExampleFK` is `NULL` because you have not set it in the `INSERT` statement.  This has nothing to do with the foreign key definition.

Comment: You expected SQL server to magically fill the IDs?

Comment: Just because you *add* a foreign key constraint to a column doesn't mean that column is *automagically* filled with valid FK values (if the column had `NULL` before - it will still have `NULL` after you add the FK constraint) - you need to do this **yourself**.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key Not Populating with Primary Key Values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9046879/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you have NULLS is when you add the foreign key to tbl_Example it references
tbl_Example1 (Example1ID)

So this is not a 1 to 1 relationship meaning tbl_Example1 PK does not auto fill

what this means is any tbl_Example1  PK can be filled into tbl_Example as  FK
you need to enforce this through the application or through the database in another way

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking that “ADD FOREIGN KEY” will insert values? It just creates the constraint. You have to update the rows now.